# How do you load nuget typescript packages on mac?

Tags: macos, typescript

I'm on a mac with Yosemite. Some people talk about loading nugget packages for TS dev. I'd like to do that, but nuget is only available on PC from what I see.

Answer (score 0):

You can get them quite easily if you use the *free* xamarin studio:

https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-studio-and-nuget/

You need to download / start installer for xamarin ... but then only pick `studio` ;)